# Chrome Notification permission always return "denied"

Tags: google-chrome, notifications, progressive-web-apps

I stuck with the case when on Chrome on an Android device (Android 14)
i want to ask permission for Notification from my site:

...

```
Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
 console.log('Permission: ', permission); });
-> Permission: denied
```

but if i set a breakpoint and check in console:
-> **Notification.permission**
i receive:
-> **'default'**

Can't understand why is that. I cleared cash, site settings, storage etc.
It is an HTTPS site.

Notification settings are enabled for Chrome.
Maybe someone is faced with that?